# Error: The argument type 'List<Book>' can't be assigned to the > parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart, casting, typeerror

I have a `book.dart` file like:

```
class Books with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final String userID;
  final String scale;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final Map<int, String> reward;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String videoUrl;
  final String created_at;
  final String updated_at;

  Books(
      {required this.id,
      required this.userID,
      required this.scale,
      required this.title,
      required this.description,
      required this.reward,
      required this.imageUrl,
      required this.videoUrl,
      required this.created_at,
      required this.updated_at});
}
```

And a `book.dart` file like below:

```
  Future<void> fetchAndSetBooksLocal() async {
    var url = Uri.parse(
        'http://10.0.2.2:${dotenv.env['BOOKS_SERVICE_PORT']}/api/books-local');

    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData =
          json.decode(response.body.toString());
    }
  }
```

The result for `extractedData` looks like below:

> [{id: 7b683abf-1894-416d-a65c-9868eeba1fe8, created_at:
> 2023-02-13T21:39:15.121Z, description: books, image_url: some_url,
> reward: {100: dollar}, scale: local, title: first, updated_at:
> 2023-02-13T21:39:15.121Z, user_id:
> 9de94696-a441-4f4e-976f-b409449fa0ac, video_url: some2 url}, {id:
> c3aab1bf-6de2-4cc0-9f3a-747e43516a69, created_at:
> 2023-02-13T21:47:37.065Z, description: books, image_url: some_url2,
> reward: {200: dollar}, scale: local, title: second, updated_at:
> 2023-02-13T21:47:37.065Z, user_id:
> ae905310-c472-4abf-a00f-a0790aae2808, video_url: some2 url2}]

When I change that line like the following:

```
final extractedData = json.decode(response.body.toString() as List<Book>);
```

I get this error that I don't know why?

> Error: The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the
> parameter type 'String'. books.dart:54
>
> - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
> - 'Book' is from 'package:front/providers/book.dart' ('lib/providers/book.dart'). bookst.dart:1
>   json.decode(response.body.toString() as List);

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize json to convert it to  `Book` object

```
class Book {
  const Book({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    ...
    ...
  });

  /// Creates a Book from Json map
  factory Book.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Book(
        id: json['id'] as int?,
        title: json['title'] as String,
      );

  final int? id;
  final String title;
  ...
  ...
}
```

And finally after API call

```js
class BooksApi {
  Future<List<Book>> fetchBooks() async {
    var url = Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:BOOKS_SERVICE_PORT/api/books-local');

    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final data = json.decode(response.body) as List<dynamic>;
      return data.map((e) => Book.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>)).toList();
    } catch (_) {
      throw Exception('Error fetching books');
    }
  }
}
```

[Check out json and serialization for more info.](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json)